# Browser hangs on reading large folder on client side

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I am trying to create a simple folder uploader (client side). The minimum required functionality is to be able to select a folder/file(s) and show on the browser the information of all files. I have used a simple input element:

```
const ReadFolder = () => {
    const onFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => console.log(event.target.files);
    return (
        <input
          type='file'
          directory
          webkitdirectory
          multiple
          onChange={onFileChange}
        />
    );
}
```

The `onFileChange` function just shows the info of received file list.

It works fine for small folders, but when I try to upload a git repository from my computer (which has a large nested folder hierarchy), the browser window becomes unresponsive for around 2 minutes before the `onChange` event is reported. Is there a way I can avoid this unresponsiveness? Can I push this processing to background (or to a web worker)?

Comment: How exactly can I?

Comment: @NotABot - I don't think we can help you without seeing what `onFileChange` is doing. Side note: `onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => onFileChange(event)}` could be just `onChange={onFileChange}`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have updated the code. I don't think it matters what the `onFileChange` function do as it will never receive the event before the browser crashing which is the actual problem. Anyways I have added a sample definition of the function and in case you are wondering, the problem exists with this code snippet as well :(

Comment: same problem with vue3

Answer (score 0):

This processing may not even be done by the browser's process, but rather by the OS directly, which is building a list of metadata for all the files in the directory and its sub-directories. That is a lot of I/O.
You are not the first one to report such an issue with some configurations (OS or file system, it's still unclear to me) having trouble to generate files' metadata when being asked by the browser through the <input type="file">.

So moving whatever to a Worker would most probably not help at all. My educated guess would be that your HDD is the bottleneck, not the CPU.

What you can try [in supporting browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showDirectoryPicker#browser_compatibility), is to request a handle over the directory rather than requesting all the files in a single call.
The new File System API has a [showDirectoryPicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showDirectoryPicker) method which would allow you to gain access to the directory, and to read only the files you need, and if you need them all, to do this in a streaming manner, allowing your page to render part of what has already been parsed while it is being parsed.

You can see a [live demo here](https://root-stealth-barometer.glitch.me/), which will currently only work in Chrome.

Note that [directories gotten from a drag&drop event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/webkitGetAsEntry) should not be read entirely either, and that you should also be able to navigate them by batches, with [better browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/webkitGetAsEntry#browser_compatibility), so if you can, try to make your UI force your users to use this method instead.

Comment: Google drive also supports folder upload, but I didn't encounter this problem while uploading there. How have they implemented this if it were an OS issue

Comment: On my OS the page is not really unresponsive, but the onchange takes a lot of time to fire. I just tried uploading the full Chromium sources to drive.google and it crashed my Firefox and on Chrome it made my laptop believe it's an helicopter, so I killed it before I get any onchange there. But FWIW, they apparently do use a simple <input webkitdirectory>, at least on macOS, maybe on windows they do use some Chrome plugins (I know they do on other Google sites), which would enable the same feature I used in [my demo](https://root-stealth-barometer.glitch.me/).

Comment: This is exactly what I want. But I guess this can't be implemented in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox and Safari at least)?

Comment: No currently only Chrome has implemented it.